# Understanding how to create a heap in Python

Tags: python, heap

The `collections.Count.most_common` function in Python uses the `heapq` module to return the count of the most common word in a file, for instance.

I have traced through the `heapq.py` file, but I'm having a bit of trouble understanding how a heap is created/updated with respect to words let's say.

So, I think the best way for me to understand it, is to figure out how to create a heap from scratch.

Can someone provide a pseudocode for creating a heap that would represent word count?

Comment: see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap#Building_a_heap

Answer (score 14, accepted):

this is a slightly modified version of the code found here : http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577086-heap-sort/

```
def HeapSort(A,T):
    def heapify(A):
        start = (len(A) - 2) / 2
        while start >= 0:
            siftDown(A, start, len(A) - 1)
            start -= 1

    def siftDown(A, start, end):
        root = start
        while root * 2 + 1 <= end:
            child = root * 2 + 1
            if child + 1 <= end and T.count(A[child]) < T.count(A[child + 1]):
                child += 1
            if child <= end and T.count(A[root]) < T.count(A[child]):
                A[root], A[child] = A[child], A[root]
                root = child
            else:
                return

    heapify(A)
    end = len(A) - 1
    while end > 0:
        A[end], A[0] = A[0], A[end]
        siftDown(A, 0, end - 1)
        end -= 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    text = "the quick brown fox jumped over the the quick brown quick log log"
    heap = list(set(text.split()))
    print heap

    HeapSort(heap,text)
    print heap
```

Output

```
['brown', 'log', 'jumped', 'over', 'fox', 'quick', 'the']
['jumped', 'fox', 'over', 'brown', 'log', 'the', 'quick']
```

you can visualize the program here
http://goo.gl/2a9Bh

Comment: Hi,from @Hueston Rido's answer it seems like pushing and popping from a heap automatically sorts the data, which looks very simple in the face of the heap sort code you've posted. I'm definitely missing something here. Could you please explain why you haven't simply pushed and popped from a heap to sort your data?

Comment: In case we want to visualize the binary tree (sort process step by step), during the tree, should we use a binary tree or just a list.

Comment: I was under the impression that OP had to not use the builtin heapq ...

Answer (score 40):

In Python 2.X and 3.x, heaps are supported through an importable library, heapq. It supplies numerous functions to work with the heap data structure modelled in a Python list.
Example:

```
>>> from heapq import heappush, heappop
>>> heap = []
>>> data = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 2, 4, 6, 8, 0]
>>> for item in data:
        heappush(heap, item)

>>> ordered = []
>>> while heap:
        ordered.append(heappop(heap))

>>> ordered
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> data.sort()
>>> data == ordered
True
```

You can find out more about Heap functions: `heappush, heappop, heappushpop, heapify, heapreplace` in [heap python docs](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/library/heapq.html).

Answer (score 17):

Here's another variation based on [Sedgewick](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/24pq/)

The heap is represented internally in an array where if a node is at k, it's children are at 2*k and 2*k + 1.  The first element of the array is not used, to make the math more convenient.

To add a new element to the heap, you append it to the end of the array and then call swim repeatedly until the new element finds its place in the heap.

To delete the root, you swap it with the last element in the array, delete it and then call sink until the swapped element finds its place.

```
swim(k):
  while k > 1 and less(k/2, k):
    exch(k, k/2)
    k = k/2

sink(k):
  while 2*k <= N:
    j = 2*k
    if j < N and less(j, j+1):
      j++
    if not less(k, j):
      break
    exch(k, j)
    k = j
```

Here's a visualization of heap insert, inserting the first 15 letters of the alphabet: [a-o]

[image: heap insert visualization]

Comment: this is great! I just wish it were a little slower or that there were a way to pause/restart it.

Comment: oh glad you like it!  It's just an animated gif.  I made it a few years ago - not even sure if I still have the code!  :)

Answer (score 5):

Your confusion may come from the fact that the Python module [`heapq`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html) does **not** define a heap as a data **type** (a class) with its own methods (e.g. as in a [`deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) or a `list`). It instead provides functions that you can run on a Python `list`.

It's best to think of `heapq` as a module providing a set of *algorithms* (methods) to interpret lists as heaps and manipulate them accordingly. Note that it's common to [represent heaps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap#Heap_implementation) internally as [arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_data_structure) (as an abstract data structure), and Python already has lists serving that purpose, so it makes sense for `heapq` to just provide methods to manipulate lists as heaps.

Let's see this with an example. Starting with a simple Python list:

```
>>> my_list = [2, -1, 4, 10, 0, -20]
```

To create a heap with `heapq` from `my_list` we just need to call `heapify` which simply re-arranges the elements of the list to form a min-heap:

```
>>> import heapq
>>> # NOTE: This returns NoneType:
>>> heapq.heapify(my_list)
```

Note that you can still access the list underlying the heap, since all `heapify` has done is change the [**value** referenced by `my_list`](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html):

```
>>> my_list
[-20, -1, 2, 10, 0, 4]
```

Popping elements from the heap held by `my_list`:

```
>>> [heapq.heappop(my_list) for x in range(len(my_list))]
[-20, -1, 0, 2, 4, 10]
```